# split the String by given number of letters

Tags: python

Is there a way to split a string by like splitting

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

to

`['The qu', 'ick br', 'own fo', 'x jump', 's over', ' the l', 'azy do', 'g.']`

?

Comment: What is the criteria? 6 characters per split?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please define the rule, according to which you want to perform the split. An example is not enough. Do you want to split into chunks of 6 characters?

Comment: Please read stackoverflow asking guidelines. This isn't a get your homework done site. Show us what you have come up with so far and where you are facing the problem.

Comment: lol it's not my homework...I was working on my project which requires a lit python but I have only learned Java and C so I just completely not sure what method I should apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to split by a particular number of characters, consider using a list comprehension alongside the `step` parameter of `range`:

```
>>> x = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
>>> N = 6
>>> [x[i:i+N] for i in range(0, len(x), N)]
['The qu', 'ick br', 'own fo', 'x jump', 's over', ' the l', 'azy do', 'g.']
>>>
```

`range(0, len(x), N)` will return increments of `N` until `len(x)`. We may use this as the starting index for each slice, and then take `N` characters after that index, as `x[i:i+N]`.